# Track the amount of traffic each author brings to a WordPress site with google analytics and google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to track the amount of traffic each author brings to a WordPress site.

The following tracking code is added with google tag manager:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx-x']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

I added a custom dimension named Author, type Integer and index 1,
that is all I did on the google analytics dashboard.

In the footer.php file of the theme I added the following code:

```
<?php
if (is_single()) {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  

    _gaq.push(['_setPageGroup', 1, '<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author()); ?>']); 
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

});
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

But it does not work. I do not know what to do next.

Also where on the google analytics dashboard should I see the report for the custom dimension?

Comment: First thing, upgrade your code to the current version of Google Analytics. Next, use a custom dimension (not supported by your code version).

Answer (score 0):

As Eike mentions, update your tracking script to Universal Analytics.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

You can find this in the Admin of Google Analytics, Admin > Property > Tracking Info > Tracking Code.

You then configure your Custom Dimension (CD) in Google Analytics.

Admin > Property > Custom Definitions > Custom Dimensions > + New Custom Dimension.

When you make your CD, set the scope to Hit level and take note of the index number, if its your first it will be one. Upon creating it will provide you the script you need to include on page.

Lastly update your tracking code on the website.

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');

ga('set', 'dimension1', '');

ga('send', 'pageview');

Once data is collected you can use custom reports, segments or bring in this value using the secondary dimensions option under most reports.